# Get Multiple id in Where Condition Node With MySQL Loopback

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopback

### **## Node ##

Loopback Node**

**Like select Fetch Multiple Category Id From Product Table.**

Pass your category id in above Bold Parameter

```
let tempQuery += " `categoryId` IN  " + **categoryId**;
            
var query = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE  **tempQuery** ";
```

Above Code will give response Like...

It fetches all categories and gives in response now in temp query variable matches category id with the response and return products if matches any

If In **SQL**
consider **1,2,3,4,5** as **Id**

```
"select * from info WHERE `id` IN ('1,2,3,4,5')"
```

Comment: And what is your question? PS. Select either MySQL or SQL Server (they're too different) and remove wrong tag.

Comment: What you want to achieve ?

Comment: Want to hit this query via loopback?

Answer (score 0):

I find it really difficult to understand your question. Are you trying to write a LoopBack query to match multiple ids? If that's the case, then you can use the `inq` operator as described [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html#inq).

```
const filter = {where: {id: {inq: [1,2,3,4,5]}}};

// LoopBack 3.x
const found = await Category.find(filter);

// LoopBack 4.x
const found = await categoryRepo.find(filter);
```